# clang 5.0.0 difference on coliru/godbolt involving virtual function

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer, linker-errors, virtual-functions

I really hope I am missing something, but consider the following code:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void doit() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void doit_internal(int n);

    void doit() {
        doit_internal(3);
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived;
}
```

On [clang (`5.0.0-3~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)`)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3723d1ca9d985d7e) I get a linker error (`undefined reference to Derived::doit_internal(int)'`). I wonder why `doit_internal` is needed if it is not actually called at all.

Moreover, on [clang (`version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final 334239)`)](https://godbolt.org/z/nAq1mS), it compiles fine.

Which of the clangs is correct? Is there a technical reason/platform specific thing/something in the standard mandating `doit_internal` to be defined?

Comment: Godbolt does not run code (and also does not link it). Coliru does. As this is a linker error, it is why you get no error on Godbolt. Your code is still malformed though as others said.

Comment: If an object of a polymorphic class is constructed, it's difficult for the linker to determine which of its virtual functions are guaranteed to not be called virtually, via a base class. It requires logic that goes beyond the usual simple analysis. (Non virtual calls are easy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. In defining `doit` you odr-used `doit_internal` (you wrote an expression that calls `doit_internal`). It makes no difference that your program can be optimized to a `return 0;`

The standard explicitly says:

> **[basic.def.odr]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4) Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every
>   non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program
>   outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required. The
>   definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in
>   the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is
>   implicitly defined (see [class.ctor], [class.dtor] and [class.copy]).
>   An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation
>   unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement.

Clang is well within its right to reject it, or not to reject it. It can even change its behavior between releases, because your program violates the requirement above.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases program compiles correctly.
But on `coliru` it fails during linking linking process, since there is no definition of `Derived::doit_internal(int)`.

`Compiler Explorer` do not run the code, it just shows assembly code for C++ code defined for current translation unit. So it doesn't have to do linking. Since linking stage is not performed, problem is not discovered and error is  not reported.

Answer (score 1):

`doit_internal` is required because one of your functions references it. Whilst that function itself is not referenced it is sill part of the application and so its dependencies are required by the linker.

If you enable optimisations then clang omits the implementation of `doit` and your application links successfully: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8496f4e097d2f0ee

godbolt is only a compiler, it doesn't link or run anything which is why it doesn't show any link errors. Notice it does still have `call    Derived::doit_internal(int)` in the assembly so if you took this assembly and tried to link it you'd end up with the same linker error.